# Is it possible to pass data within an async function outside of the class it is in?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

I am using Ionic React with Capacitor to try to extract the geolocation and then attempting to store it within a database. I am trying to store the value within App.coordinate but whenever I try to export it to map.ts it will store it in the database as undefined.

Is there anyway to pass on the geolocation data from the getCurrentPosition() function to map.ts?

As you can see I've tried numerous ways to try to pass the data (as seen by static coordinate / coord! variables).

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { all } from '../server/db/maps';
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    state: any = {};
    props: any = {};
    lat!: number;
    long!: number;
    static coordinate: string;
    coord!: string;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { maps: [] };
        this.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    async getCurrentPosition() {
        const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.long = position.coords.longitude;
        this.coord = "[" + this.long + ", " + this.lat + "]";
        App.coordinate = "[" + this.long + ", " + this.lat + "]";
        console.log('Current', App.coordinate);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let r = await fetch('/api/maps');
            let maps = await r.json();
            this.setState({ maps });
        } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main className="container my-5">
                <h1 className="text-primary text-center">Geolocation</h1>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.maps.map(maps =>{ return <li className="list-group-item">{maps.id}, {maps.date}, {maps.coordinates} </li> })}
                </ul>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export let Coordinates = App.coordinate; //App.coordinate passes on undefined
export interface IAppProps {}
export interface IAppState { maps: Array<{ id: string, date: Date, coordinates: string }>; }
export default App;
```

maps.ts

```
import { Connection } from './index';
import { App, Coordinates } from '../../client/app';

export const all = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Connection.query('SELECT * FROM COORDINATES', (err, results) => {

            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(results);
        });

        let stmt = 'INSERT INTO COORDINATES (id, date, coordinates) VALUES ? ';
        let todos = [['3343', '2020-01-09 22:00:00', '[44.44444, 55.55555]'],
                     ['5555', '2020-01-09 22:01:00', Coordinates]];
        Connection.query(stmt, [todos], (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
              return console.error(err.message);
            }
            // get inserted rows
            console.log('Row inserted:' + results.affectedRows);
          });
    });
}

export default {
    all
}
```

Comment: Are you storing the coordinates after they get generated? This looks like you are trying to get them before they are generated so it justs returns undefined

Comment: @ManelAlonso that is precisely the problem I am having. I have tried various ways for the past few days on trying to store the coordinate values but "await" prevents me from storing it in such a way I can pass it to my query.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you're trying to do, **won't** work

**Why?**

Because you would need an instance of App class to access its 'coordinate'.
Even though you are using a static variable, this variable it's only filled dynamically, not statically.

**How to solve it?**

You will only solve this problem by calling dynamically a method to store the coordinates, and separating the insertion logic from the listing logic as well.

Look:

```
export const all = async() => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        Connection.query('SELECT * FROM COORDINATES', (err, results) => {
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
)

export const save = async (coordinates) => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Make use of const variables as well
        const stmt = 'INSERT INTO COORDINATES (id, date, coordinates) VALUES ? ';
        const todos = [['3343', '2020-01-09 22:00:00', '[44.44444, 55.55555]'],
                     ['5555', '2020-01-09 22:01:00', coordinates]]; // dynamic variable, not static.
        Connection.query(stmt, [todos], (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
              return console.error(err.message);
            }
            // get inserted rows
            console.log('Row inserted:' + results.affectedRows);
          });
    });
)
```

And then, you would call it from the App and preferably on the componentDidMount (because it's an async function)

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        let r = await fetch('/api/maps');
        let maps = await r.json();
        this.setState({ maps });
        await this.getCurrentPosition()
        // ... call to server to save this.coord
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
}

async getCurrentPosition() {
    const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.long = position.coords.longitude;
    this.coord = "[" + this.long + ", " + this.lat + "]";
    console.log('this.coord', this.coord);
}
```